# Users rate and comment each other after an event?

Tags: users, comments, rating

I'm working on a project where users trade services (like AirBNB or Uber). I'm a bit stuck at the stage when the task is done and the two users have to rate each other. I have ratings sorted using [Voting API](https://www.drupal.org/project/votingapi) and [Fivestar](https://www.drupal.org/project/fivestar) but don't quite know how to handle Comments. They shouldn't be open all the time.

I've played around with user comments but it doesn't have Views field support. I then created a "Comments" content type and am trying to use that.

Any other ideas?

Comment: you can create a comments view, and then include that as a field in the main view - when you say they shouldn't be open all the time, what do you mean - what are you trying to present to the user, and how would they then view the comments if desired?

Comment: I don't want users to be able to comment on users except for when an even has occurred. So by default, users can view other users comments by going to their profile (I'll create a contextual view and use panels to add it to the user profile page). I'm trying to figure out the mechanism for users commenting on each other after an event.